# Storing objects in a timetable

Tags: java, time, schedule, temporal, timetable

In my program, there is a global clock, and time is split into discrete 'scenes'.

There exists a global `Schedule`, which is a `HashMap<Scene, HashMap<User, Action>>`

Each `User` object has a `startTime` and an `endTime`.
I want to be able to set these times in the `User` object. 
When I query the `Schedule`, and say "what is happening at time x?", I need the `User` objects whose `startTime <= x` and `endTime > x`.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Implement a method that takes a time and does the check you mention and then call this method using streams and lambda functionality

Comment: I’m not getting which part of it you got trouble with? Sorry… And Stack Overflow isn’t a design service. So how would an answer that doesn’t present a design look like??